# What standard governs the dimensions of SMT chip resistors and capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, surface-mount, packages, standard

I am aware of the [JEDEC registered outlines](http://www.jedec.org/category/technology-focus-area/registered-outlines-jep95), which define the standard mechanical dimensions and tolerances for a wide variety of solid-state packages.

However, these standards do not appear to cover two-terminal SMT resistors and capacitors (e.g. 0603, 0805, etc.).  [IPC-SM-782](http://www.tortai-tech.com/upload/download/2011102023233369053.pdf) has dimensions and tolerances for these, but this standard has been superceded by [IPC-7351](http://shop.ipc.org/IPC-7351B-English-D), which no longer includes this data.

What standard currently governs the standard dimensions of these components?

Comment: I don't think that means the IPC-SM-782 footprints are invalid -- I'd use them. Also I think these are copyrighted documents and while I appreciate the links, a moderator may need to unlink them.

Answer (score 11):

The answer *may* be [IEC 60115-8](http://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/artnum/047462) for resistors, and [IEC 60384-21](http://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/artnum/045892) and [IEC 60384-22](http://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/artnum/045893) for capacitors.

However, further research suggests that the primary source *should* actually be [EIA PDP-100](http://global.ihs.com/doc_detail.cfm?document_name=EIA%20PDP%20100%20RENEWAL&item_s_key=00118546) – if it were up to date. The latest edition of this appears to be from either [1987](http://www.ecaus.org/engineering/detailsStds.cfm?id1=794) or [1992](http://www.ecaus.org/engineering/detailsStds.cfm?id1=549). There's a convoluted history you can dive into at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Industries_Alliance), [JEDEC](http://www.jedec.org/about-jedec/jedec-history), and [ECIA](http://www.eciaonline.org/eiastandards/), but the short story is that the EIA is no more, and the EIA standards are now maintained by the [ECIA](http://www.eciaonline.org/). There is [some](http://global.ihs.com/doc_detail.cfm?rid=ECIA&item_s_key=00118546) [evidence](http://www.ecaus.org/engineering/committees/P4/EIA-ECA%20PDP-100%20%28Draft%202%29.pdf) that a new edition of PDP-100 has been worked on, but [there doesn't appear to be much activity right now](http://www.eciaonline.org/standards/committees/p4/p4.cfm).

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you want to.